# How to track changes on VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to be able to log the modifications as values and track them on a different sheet. Right now, when the modified cell contains a formula, my code logs the previous value in a separate sheet correctly as a value, but for some reason, the new value still appears as a formula. I want that new value to be displayed as a value, not a formula. Additionally, it appears that the log only functions when I click on the cell. However, I would like for the log to work whenever the value is updated—for example, when a formula calculates a new value automatically when a refresh happens—rather than only when I click on the cell manually. Thanks for the assistance.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim RangeValues As Variant, r As Long, boolOne As Boolean, TgValue 'the array to keep Target values     (before UnDo)
    Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = Worksheets("Log - Ratio")
    Dim UN As String: UN = Application.UserName
    
    
      'sh.Unprotect "" 'it should be good to protect the sheet
     If sh.Range("A1") = "" Then sh.Range("A1").Resize(1, 6) = _
                                     Array("Time", "User Name", "Changed cell", "From", "To", "Sheet      Name")

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False                                     'to optimize the code (make it   faster)
     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

     If Intersect(Target, Me.Range("O32:CL32")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
     If Target.Cells.count > 1 Then
        TgValue = extractData(Target)
     Else
        TgValue = Array(Array(Target.Formula, Target.Address(0, 0)))  'put the target range in an array (or  as a string for a single cell)
        boolOne = True
     End If
     Application.EnableEvents = False                                'avoiding to trigger the change event   after UnDo
     Application.Undo
     RangeValues = extractData(Target)                           'define the RangeValue
     putDataBack TgValue, ActiveSheet                            'put back the changed data
     If boolOne Then Target.Offset(1).Select
     Application.EnableEvents = True

     Dim columnHeader As String, rowHeader As String
     For r = 0 To UBound(RangeValues)
        If RangeValues(r)(0) <> TgValue(r)(0) Then
            sh.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(1, 6).Value = _
                Array(Now, UN, RangeValues(r)(1), RangeValues(r)(0), TgValue(r)(0), Target.Parent.Name)
        End If
     Next r
 
    'sh.Protect ""
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub

Sub putDataBack(arr, sh As Worksheet)
Dim i As Long, arrInt, El
For Each El In arr
    sh.Range(El(1)).Value = El(0)
Next
End Sub

Function extractData(Rng As Range) As Variant
    Dim a As Range, arr, count As Long, i As Long
    ReDim arr(Rng.Cells.count - 1)
    For Each a In Rng.Areas 'creating a jagged array containing the values and the cells address
        For i = 1 To a.Cells.count
            arr(count) = Array(a.Cells(i).Value, a.Cells(i).Address(0, 0)): count = count + 1
        Next
    Next
    extractData = arr
End Function
```

Comment: This sounds like a huge task and therefore very slow as you have described it. Try copying the whole workbook and then scanning and comparing the two with VBA each time you can detect a change. Good luck!

Comment: @user10186832, so you're saying there is no way to catch a change everytime a formula refreshes?

Comment: Not as far as I know. *only when I click on the cell manually* - this is the only time you would get a trigger for VBA to check. Stand-alone Excel only saves a few changes itself to support the `undo` action. A shared workbook has limitations for what you can see when you check for changes. As you have described it the requirement is to check *any* cell which could involve millions of values even on a single sheet.

Comment: what if we only ask for checking only changes to specific cells?The problem remains the trigger , because for the use case I want, most of the changes would happpen when the underlying formula on that cell refreshes the value,. If you have a way to do that, I would certainly appreciate it @user10186832

Comment: This may help, [an Excel clock](https://davetallett26.github.io/excelclock.html). Trigger every second as written.